# Is it possible to check-in a small bag which is usually used as a cabin bags?

Tags: hand-luggage, check-in

My handbag size is 36*22*54 cm (18"), it is a small size which is normally used as a handbag. But I like to feel free and don't want to have it with me all the trip. So I would like to check it in. Is it possible to check in these small sizes?! Or they will inforce me to use it as a handbag!

Comment: Which airline ?

Comment: It will probably be air france. or KLM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I have seen small bags that could have been carried going around on the baggage belt. I have personally checked a bag larger than a purse, but small enough that it could be carried on, on several occasions with several different airlines.

Some important considerations:

- can you close it completely and securely? If you mean "handbag" like the North American word "purse", not all such bags zip shut, they may just have a clasp. You need to make sure nothing will fall out no matter how the bag is turned, dropped, thrown etc.
- Does it have prominent handles (as some purses and backpacks do) that might catch on handling equipment? If so you should work out how to constrain them - bungee cords, wrapping in plastic, or the like
- lithium batteries, including spare laptop batteries or external batteries for phones, are not allowed in **checked** luggage. If you have such things you will need to move them to whatever you are carrying on.
- You may be charged a fee for each bag you check

Other than that I don't expect a problem. I have yet to meet an airline that had a minimum size limit for checked bags.

Comment: Yes, I too have checked-in 2 hand/cabin bags (out of 4 as me and my wife was allowed 4 in total) while coming to US from India via Emirates. Actually, in my case Airline crew member himself asked me that I can check-in hand bags (if I want) as a checked-in luggage, so I did.

Comment: I have in fact been told that if my carry on size bag was under a certain weight I could check it for free with my other bags.